# Extracing words from a string?

Tags: ruby, string, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a string `"---\n- bb\n- j2me\n"`. I want to extract the words and save it into an array. Like `['bb','j2me']`. I tried the below but its not working.

```
 "---\n- bb\n- j2me\n".split("\n")
```

If you have any idea please share.

Comment: Question is not clear. Define "word". `"j2me"` is not a word in any regularly known sense. What gives you that array? Do you simply want to split by a sequence of `"\n"` `" "`, and `"-"`?

Comment: Do you want something like `str.scan(/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/) #=> ["bb", "j2me"]`?  Why the Rails tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks like [YAML](http://www.yaml.org):

```
puts "---\n- bb\n- j2me\n"
# ---
# - bb
# - j2me
```

You can parse it with:

```
require 'yaml'

YAML.load("---\n- bb\n- j2me\n")
#=> ["bb", "j2me"]
```